# trigger function as soon as pop up editor opens

Tags: jquery

I have a pop up editor which there is a dropdown list inside,but I want this drop down list bind as soon as I load the pop up editor,if I use document(ready) then this function is Unknown when I want to call it ,what should I do?

```
                        function onChange() {
                            selectedText = $("#DeviceType").val();


                            $.ajax({
                                dataType: "json",
                                type: "POST",
                                url: "@Url.Action("modelProducer","AdminTool")",
                                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                                data: JSON.stringify({ "turbineType": selectedText, }),
                                success: function (data) {
                                    modelProducerResult = data;
                                    var ddl = $("#ModelProducer").data("kendoDropDownList");
                                    // ddl.dataSource.data({}); // clears dataSource
                                    ddl.text(""); // clears visible text
                                    ddl.value("");
                                    $("#ModelProducer").data("kendoDropDownList").dataSource.data(data);

                                }
                            });
                        };
```

I use the onChange function here:

```
 function deviceTypesList(container, options) {
                        $('<input  name="DeviceType" id="DeviceType" data-type="string" \">')
                          .appendTo(container)
                          .kendoDropDownList({
                              dataSource:mydata_deviceType,
                              dataTextField: "Text",
                              dataValueField: "Text",
                              valuePrimitive: true,
                              change: onChange
                              //dataValueField: "ProductName",
                         });
```

Comment: update the code to load the pop up editor

Comment: @Rex what do you mean?